# decoding array inputs and while loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, conditional-statements

I basically just need help decoding this code in matlab,  what does each line mean and what does it do?

Basically, Create an array, g, where each value in g is the previous value of g, but squared. Stop when g reaches a value at or greater than 100 times the original value of g.

```
g = input('Please provide an initial value: '); 

while ((g == 1) || (g == 0))    
           disp('Cannot be 0 or 1')    
           g = input('Please provide an initial value: ');
end

i = 1; 
while ((g(i)^2)<=(100*g(1)))    
        g(i+1) = g(i)^2;    
        i = i+1; 
end

g = g'
```

The code, asks for a number that cannot be 0 or 1.  The number is then squared but stops when the next value is less than or equal to 100 times the initial number.

for example if you input 2
the code will spit out 2, 4, 16, and will stop because the next value is 256, which is greater than 2 * 100 = 200.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: You ask what the code does, then explain what the code does. I don't understand what you are asking here. You can type in `help xxx` in MATLAB to get help about `xxx`. Do that with each word in the code you don't understand and presto!

Comment: I recommend that, instead of asking such a question here, you step through the code in the debugger (simply click on the left margin for the first line of code, to create a break point, then run the code). You'll see what each line does and how it changes the variables involved. You can also type in parts of expressions into the MATLAB command prompt to see what they do. Explore stuff for yourself, don't depend on other people to explain things to you. You will learn a lot more that way. If there is one statement that really stumps you, ask a question about that one statement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = input('Please provide an initial value: '); 
//print this out to screen ; wait for user to type in ; press enter ;
// g becomes the number that the user type in ;
while ((g == 1) || (g == 0))    
// while g equals to 1 or g equals to zero ;
    disp('Cannot be 0 or 1')    
//print this statement to screen / console ;
    g = input('Please provide an initial value: ');
//print this out to screen ; wait for user to type in ; press enter ;
// g becomes the number that the user type in ;
end
// end the while loop ;
i = 1; 
// let i be the counter / index ; only to control the looping ;
while ((g(i)^2)<=(100*g(1)))    
// while i-th element of g is less than or equal to 100 times first element of g ;
    g(i+1) = g(i)^2;    
// i+1-th element of g is define as i-th element of g squared ;
// note that g actually becomes an array when this statement runs ;
    i = i+1; 
// i is define as i plus 1 ; meaning if i was 1 i is now 2 ;
end
// end the while loop ;
g = g'
// g become g transpose ; Matlab default to row array so this make it column array ;
```